# Casting pointer as an array of chars?

Tags: c++, pointers, assembly, memory, 64-bit

Is there a way that I can take a pointer and cast the address as the little-endian representation?

I am writing an array of char[] (as bytecode) in the following syntax:

```
char toWrite[] = "\x50\x48\xB8\x77\x77\x77\x77\x77\x77\x77\x77\xFF\xE0";
```

I would like to take the pointer and add the address into where all of the 7s are, so when disassembled and the address were 0xDEADBEEFDEADBEEF, the code would read:

```
50 48 B8 EF BE AD DE EF BE AD DE
```

or in ASM as

```
push rax
mov rax, 0xDEADBEEFDEADBEEF
jmp rax
```

Comment: You want this all to happen at compile time, correct? At runtime it's just a `memcpy` or a loop that `memcpy`s backward on a big endian system.

Comment: @user4581301 It will be happening on runtime. The code producing this is a member function of an object that stores the pointer. Didn't think it was that simple. Thanks!

Comment: Not a problem. Just remember to take the address of the pointer in the call to `memcpy` or you'll just copy whatever the pointer points to. `memcpy(&toWrite[3],&myPointer, sizeof(myPointer));`